# how to add comments in image matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

i have created a matlab code which calculates length and breadth of all rectangles in an image
result comes in the command window.

But i wanted that the result should come in the image itself with length and breadth alongside of each rectangle.

my code is

```
I = imread('F:\h.png'); 
info = imfinfo('F:\h.png');
I1 = ~im2bw(I); 
I2 = bwlabel(I1);
S = regionprops(I2, {'BoundingBox'});
[m,n] = size(S);
for a=1:m
    for b=1:n
        width = S(a,b).BoundingBox(3);
        height = S(a,b).BoundingBox(4);
        if width==height
            display('square');
        else
            display('rectangle');
        end
        display(width);
        display(height);
        pause(2)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [text(x,y,'string')](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/text.html)

string in quotes to the location specified by the point (x,y) on the image.

Example :
`text(width/2,height/2,'square');`

Comment: no in this each time we have to provide location bt in my case there are number of rectangles in one figure so its should come automatically to all the rectangles..

Answer (score 0):

```
I = imread('F:\h.png'); 
info = imfinfo('F:\h.png');
I1 = ~im2bw(I); 
I2 = bwlabel(I1);
S = regionprops(I2, {'BoundingBox'});
[m,n] = size(S);
for a=1:m
    for b=1:n
        width = S(a,b).BoundingBox(3);
        height = S(a,b).BoundingBox(4);
        if width==height
            display('square');
            text(S(a,b).Centroid, 'square')
        else
            display('rectangle');
            text(S(a,b).Centroid, 'rectangle')
        end
        display(width);
        display(height);
        pause(2)
    end
end
```